# codeigniter using the name of controller in base url

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am working on a project in codeigniter. I have stuck in baseurl when I run the controller then it includes all the files of jquery and css. But when I run a function then the url of the jquery add the name of the controller.

This is my base url: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/cod_login/';`

[image]

I don't know why codeigniter is doing that.

Comment: Any code? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is happen when you don't echo base URL only (echo) is missing thanks to all for ans

Answer (score 0):

Base URL is wrong. It should be like this

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/cod_login/';

$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/poject_name'; # syntax
$config['base_url'] = 'http://stackoverflow.com/'; # example
```

**In Routes**

```
$route['default_controller'] = "defult_controler_name";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Comment: but it adding the name of controller

Comment: what is your default controller name ??

Comment: controller name is club

Comment: in here `$route['default_controller'] = "club";` change this first

Comment: i have just change the theme of the application in the old theme it working fine

Comment: in the default_controller i only have the name of the folder in which  the project exist

Comment: i have share the screen in the Question

Comment: how to share in the comments

Comment: No add in your question

Comment: @sheraziqbal if its helps please accept + vote. Thank you